# objective-c constants.h static const

Tags: objective-c

I googled a lot of similar questions, but none of them had a really good answer about what i needed.
Im wondering about the best way to write constants in some .h file.
my constants file is just a clear file with no imports, just clear .h file. I import it in prefix file.
when i use

```
static  NSInteger someInteger = 1;
```

or

```
static BOOl someBool = YES;
```

The compiler compiles okay but gives me a warning that this variable is unused even though im using it multiple times in different classes.
But if i use

```
static NSString* someString = @"";
```

there are not any warnings.

also if i use

```
const NSInteger someInteger = 1;
```

Compiler compiles okay for a real device, but when running on a simulator it does not compile with an error `duplicate symbols for architecture i386`

also what is the difference between

```
const NSString* someString = @"";
const NSInteger someInteger = 1;
```

and

```
NSString* const someString = @"";
NSInteger const someInteger = 1;
```

I ended up using `static const NSInteger someInteger =1;`, but i wonder if this is a right option.
So really my question is: what words should i use to successfully create a constants.h file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For all types (both primitive or otherwise) then you need to provide a single implementation of it somewhere:

constants.h:

```
extern const int someValue;
extern NSString * const someString;
```

constants.m:

```
const NSInteger someValue = 1;
NSString * const someString = @"Some string";
```

You never want to use `static` variables in header files as you will end up with multiple copies of the "constant" in every implementation file that includes that header (they may not upset the linker, and cause a link error, but they are there).

Comment: but when i use const NSInteger someInteger = 1; compiler throws an error about duplicate symbols

Comment: @TrenboloneA Are you using `#import "constants.h"` and not `#include "constants.h"`?  Are you sure `someInteger` isn't already declared within the implementation file?

Comment: yes, im sure. may be that is because constants is a blank sheet, not a subclass with no implementation and interface?

Comment: @TrenboloneA No, having no `@interface` is fine.  Do a search of your project for `someInteger` and check for duplication declarations.

Comment: there is none, im positive. The error is thrown only when i build on simulator though...for real device it works alright...

Comment: @TrenboloneA Please edit your question and show the complete compiler error message.

Comment: @TrenboloneA I'd like to see the names of the duplicate symbols.

Comment: @TrenboloneA Strange.  It seems to complain about the same duplicate symbols in `WSGridCreator.o` 6 times.  I think there is another issue happening here.  Have to tried to clean the project?

Comment: @TrenboloneA Sorry, I've no idea what's going on.

Comment: don't use `const int foo = 42` in header files. Use `static const` instead. Otherwise you end up with a *definition* of foo in every file that includes the header, leading to duplicate symbols.

Comment: well, thank you, you've answered my question anyway ;)

Comment: @Sebastian so i should use static const for primitive and extern id const for objects?

Comment: @TrenboloneA No, use `static` if the definition is in the header file, this will create a variable for every compilation unit including the header. Use `extern` + definition in the implementation file to share the variable between compilation units. For constants the latter case is usually preferred.

Comment: @TrenboloneA See my update.  You do, indeed, get duplicates when defining the constant value within the header file.  Therefore the best approach is to provide a `constants.m` containing the actual values.  Sebastian is wrong about using `static const` as you end up with symbols duplicated in every implementation file, which is wasteful.

Comment: @Sebastian so in .h file i would use extern CGFloat const someFloat;
and in .m file i use CGFloat const someFloat = 29;
?

Comment: @trojanfoe Please read my comment again, although I would agree that "variable" might not be the best choice of words.

Comment: @trojanfoe yes, he said that using static would cause duplications.

Comment: well, looks like that's it, Thank you guys.
The only question left is what is the difference between const NSString someString and NSString* const someString?

Comment: @Sebastian I have re-read your comment.  You say `static const` stops the *definition* of the variable in every implementation file.  That is wrong.  They are duplicated in every implementation file, however their scope is limited to that implementation file.  That is wasteful.

Comment: @trojanfoe "this will create a variable for every compilation unit including the header." (As I said before, not the best choice of words)

Comment: @Sebastian Your comments appear to contradict each other.

Comment: @trojanfoe The first comment was only about getting duplicate symbols when not using `static` with definitions in header files, the second comment was about why using `static` is actually a bad idea.

Comment: @Sebastian OK, so I've corrected my answer, so are you going to remove your downvote?